# A single vs a double consonant issue.

Tags: orthography

According to The Grammarist: [till, until and 'til](http://grammarist.com/usage/until-till-til/):

> - ***Till, as a variant of until***, is a preposition meaning up to the time of. Till—not ‘til, *an unnecessary abbreviation*—has been in the language for centuries, and there’s no reason not to use it.

Actually, *until is derived from till as Etymonline explains:*

[Until](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=until&searchmode=none)

> - ***c. 1200, from till (prep.)***. The first element is un- "as far as, up to" (also in unto), from Old Norse *und "as far as, up to," from Proto-Germanic *und- (cognates: Old English oð "up to, as far as.

[Till](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=till&searchmode=none):

> - ***Old English til (Northumbrian)  "to," from Old Norse til "to, until,"*** from Proto-Germanic *tilan (cognates: Danish til, Old Frisian til "to, till," Gothic tils "convenient," German Ziel "limit, end, goal").

- My question: is there a plausible explanation for the different end spelling of the two prepositions, *single l vs double l*?  Apparently the original term *till* had a single l in its Old English form. Is it a phonetic issue which makes the sound of till more natural with a double consonant?

Comment: The repeated consontant is merely a vestigial orthographic convention (and so not hard-and-fast) reflecting the shortness of the vowel. The Middle English/Late Middle English period is the place to look.

Comment: So why not in until?

Comment: As I said, it's vestigial and spotty.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference to this *vestigial orthographic convention* ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F245771%2Fa-single-vs-a-double-consonant-issue&ei=7O9RVcTZF5f7sAS67oCABA&usg=AFQjCNHJ8yvKxh8kUIXlTHXGeP7PLZ47qQ&sig2=U449FC__CYyB1nw9wAFlPQ

Comment: Just joking :)  http://www.thehistoryofenglish.com/history_middle.html

Comment: I would rather ask "why does until have a single l?"  Allmost all rhyming words have double l: bill, dill, drill, fill, frill, gill, grill, hill, Jill, kill, krill, mill, pill, quill, rill, sill, shill, shrill, still, swill, and will, versus nil and, arguably mil.

Comment: @phoog - that is a fair point, but  *till and until* are actually synonyms with the same root, but different orthographic evolutions.

Comment: Perhaps another interesting question is why we prefer *until* over *till* yet *to* over *unto*.

Answer (score 1):

My German grammar says in compounds and derivations of one-syllable words ending with -ll such as

- all fill full skill till

one l is dropped in British English as in

- almost although to fulfil (AmE to fulfill) skilful fully until

ll remains before -ness: dullness fullness

Source: Adolf Lamprecht, Grammatik der englischen Sprache. Publisher Cornelsen. Page 343.

Answer (score 0):

Till and Til are most likely different because the concept of standardized spelling wasn't really thought of when the word was coined. Till was most likely the more popular spelling during the time.