# Best practice regarding the words until, till, til, 'till, 'til and to

Tags: meaning, word-choice, spelling-pronunciations, variants

I often see in English the word `'till` used as `until`. Example

> I'll wait **'till** the end of time.

Now I have found out that this may be wrong. The correct writing is without the apostrophe <s>`'till`</s> and instead simply `till`.

In [this dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/should-you-use-until-or-till-or-til) among others, the word `till` is described as an old word for `until`. And while the version including an apostrophe `'till` is bad practice, the version `'til` (single `l`) is mentioned as an old-fashioned variant that people just in general don't like nowadays of some reason. The dictionary gives a few examples of actual use, for instance:

> ”Yes we will, Watty; we’re only going to wait **'til** they’ve got the house and furniture—and oh! Watty. What do you think?”
>   —The New York Observer and Chronicle, 22 Aug. 1872

It is also mentioned that a writing like `til` or `'til` may have originated from the word `to`, which then gives it a slightly different meaning than the word `until`.

I then came across [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until) that explains the writing `'til` (with one `l`) as definitely completely wrong and non-existing and only wrong-fully used now and then.

So, my question is simply to have it all summed up to get the full overview of the following:

- which of the variants below are **correct/incorrect**,
- which are **formal/informal**,
- which are **abbreviations or not** and
- which are **old-fashioned, not in common English language anymore or simply not recommended for  use**, but still correct - that is, what is best practice in each case.
- Also, are they all fully interchangeable or are there variations in their meanings?

Here are all the variants I can think of and have come across:

> - until
> - til
> - till
> - 'till
> - 'til
> - to

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6989/9368 and https://english.stackexchange.com/q/245771/9368

Comment: In general, people have stopped writing *'til* and started using *till* instead. These are different spellings of the same spoken word. And *'till* is an incorrect combination of *'til* and *till*.  [See usage note](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/'til).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "till" and "until"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until)