# 'till / by' the end of this week?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I will prepare some materials '***till*** or **by**' the end of this week.

Is there any difference in the meaning? Let us imagine today is Monday. Will you have different expectations because of this?

Comment: See this related but more generalized (and unanswered) question too https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469729/best-practice-regarding-the-words-until-till-til-till-til-and-to?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I will have prepared some materials by the end of this week.

I will be preparing some materials till the last day of week.

This can be the correct usage of the sentences.

PS: Mods, please be gentle with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Till** a certain time means the verb is continuously happening until the end of that time period. For example, *I will work till sun down* means I will continue to work until sunset. The emphasis is on the subject, the person that does the verb.

**By** means a job or task will be finished a the end of the time period, the emphasis is on the task/verb. For example, *The job will be done by sun down.*

If you say "I will be preparing some materials till the last day of week." it means you will be working all week with little or no breaks.

If you say "The materials will be prepared by the end of this week.", it means those items will be ready by the weekend.